# My screen remains black after I wake up from suspend

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, suspend, kde

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.6
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-48-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 5700G with Radeon Graphics
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT

Is there anything I can do to fix this? I have to turn it off and on every time it suspends.